# Network manager shared connection slow

Tags: networkmanager, steam

I have a laptop running nixos and a desktop pc running windows.  They are connected via a crossover cable.  I use the option "shared connection" from network manager to stream steam games from my desktop to my laptop.  The connection is very bad.  I assume it goes over the wifi-router through the crossover cable and not directly to the laptop.  The desktop has no other possibility to connect to the internet than over the crossover cable.  How can i force the desktop to connect directly to the laptop.  I assume i need a subnet with my laptop and desktop.

The setup is the following

- Laptop connects to the internet through the wifi router
- Desktop connects to the internet over the crossover cable via shared intenet from the laptop.

generated nmconnection file from networkmanager

```
[connection]
id=Shared Internet
uuid=3894ba78-6802-4755-aab1-0f427b7680f5
type=ethernet
permissions=
timestamp=1588368404

[ethernet]
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto

[proxy]
```

releveant section from `ip addr show`

```
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:6a:64:31:1c:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::65a0:9497:5026:50d7/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp61s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:1d:ea:02:db:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.106/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp61s0
       valid_lft 1802056sec preferred_lft 1802056sec
    inet6 2003:c2:a711:53f9:21f4:3d78:b54:fa56/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 604770sec preferred_lft 86370sec
    inet6 fe80::e183:dee5:d748:e98b/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

A other thing that i tried is using the following script.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s31f6 -s 10.0.0.0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s31f6 -s 10.0.0.0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s31f6 -s 10.0.0.0 -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT

# Reply to ICMP (ping) packets so clients can check their connections.
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s31f6 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s31f6 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

# Allow postrouting to wan_nic (for e.g. internet access on the subnet).
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0 -o wlp61s0 -j MASQUERADE

# Enable forwarding from subnet_nic to wan_nic (and back via related and established connections).
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s31f6 -s 10.0.0.0 -o wlp61s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


ip addr add 10.0.0.100 dev enp0s31f6
```

With this in nixos configuration

```
services.dhcpd4.extraConfig = ''
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 10.0.0.100;
  subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.0.0.150 10.0.0.250;
  }
'';
```

i got that from here https://xyne.archlinux.ca/notes/network/dhcp_with_dns.html.  But it didn't get a internet connection at all.  I can't reproduce the setup from the website exacly, because nixos works differently than other linux systems.

Comment: Rather than simply linking to a (fairly long!) page, you should describe (at least briefly) _what_ you tried that didn't work. That link may not be valid forever, and anyway users looking to answer your question shouldn't have to go offsite and slog through external documentation just to have a full understanding of your question. You can still link to the page for _additional_ detail, but it shouldn't be the **only** information provided about that part of your question.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you detail your _entire_ network setup. You start out talking about a crossover cable, but then suddenly there's mention of a WiFi router out of the blue, and it's not really clear which computers have wifi interfaces, or how exactly any of these machines may, or are supposed to, reach the internet. Details of the IP addresses / netmasks for each interface on each device would also be useful information.